# What's the difference in comparing a stored formatted datetime to another datetime and comparing a two datetimes where one is being formatted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm not sure why this errors:

```
time = Time.zone.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

time >= Time.zone.now
```

error: comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with String failed

But this does not

```
Time.zone.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') >= Time.zone.now
```

Comment: wow, even weirder: `"2023-07-10" >= Time.zone.now # => false` and `"2023-08-10" >= Time.zone.now #=> true` (results on July 10 2023). Strings are being coerced into Time objects.

Comment: The first example doesn't error for me.

Comment: That makes no sense, copy-paste actual code and the error from your Rails console please.

Comment: Les, no, the RHS is being `.to_s`ed by `String#>=`: `Time.zone.today.to_s >= Time.zone.now.to_s # => false`

Comment: @smathy Not in my testing. I assigned my time object to a variable: `t = Time.zone.now`, and overrode the `to_s` method as a singleton method on that instance: `def t.to_s; p("called to_s!"); super; end`, and then tried the same comparisons. Nothing was printed.

Comment: Rails 7.0.6/Ruby 3.2.2 -- no errors thrown -- this likely has to do with the rails and/or ruby version.  Should add those to the question.

Comment: Alexander, wow, yeah, my mistake. That's actually very different than I expected. Turns out it ends up being: `rhs.utc.to_datetime <=> lhs.to_datetime`  Freaky.

Comment: @smathy How did you determine that? I spied on `#to_datetime` using the same singleton method spy trick, and it was never called.

Comment: Went to the source. I'm guessing you didn't mock `utc` to return the object with `to_datetime` on it: `main> t = Time.current; def t.utc; Class.new(Time) { def to_datetime; puts "In mock"; super; end }.new; end; "2020-07-10" <=> t # ⇒ In mock
-1`